# Match URL to a specific file in Apache

Tags: apache

I have a domain which is currently redirecting to another page. This is my virtual hosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  Redirect permanent / http://www.anotherdomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I need an SSL certificate for that page, and to verify I must provide a file under a certain URL.

Is it possible to provide the apache configuration that matches e.g. example.com/verify_file_123.txt to a file on my filesystem, e.g. /var/www/my_site/verify_file_123.txt **while still having redirects for all other routes?**

I tried it with

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  Alias "/verify_file_123.txt" "/var/www/my_site/verify_file_123.txt"

  Redirect permanent / http://www.anotherdomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirects are processed before Aliases are processed, and therefore a request that matches a Redirect or RedirectMatch will never have Aliases applied.

You can try something like this:

```
Alias "/verify_file_123.txt" "/var/www/my_site/verify_file_123.txt"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/verify_file_123.txt
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```